# How could I perform a foreign key query

Tags: python, mysql, orm, peewee

I'm trying to get all the information of a group of tables in order to avoid N+1 problem.

I have a Peewee model called `Zone`. Also I have another object called `MyObject`. `MyObject`s belong to a `Zone`, so in my model I have declared `MyObject.zone` as ForeignField with `MyObject`s as a related parameter (how it could be accessed from zone).

Now, I want to retrieve all objects inside (with all columns) a `zone` in order to send it by JSON.
The naive approch would be a `for` loop inside `Zone.select()` and then inside the loop get the information of each `Object`. The problem with that approch is that I have a lot of entries and it will cause a N+1 problem to be notice.

The way that the Peewee documentation recommends is to do a `Join` and then get all the information in only one query, something like this:

```
Zone.select(Zone, MyObject).join(MyObject)
```

The problem here is that the returned query has N entries (where N is the number of objects) and each entry is a `Zone` with only one object, that is wrong. It should return M entries where M is the number of `Zone`s and, inside `Zone.myobjects` for each `Zone`, have a list with the number of objects that belongs to that `zone`.

```py
query = Zone.select(Zone,MyObject).join(Zone)
zones = list(query) # N zones, not M
zone[0].myobjects # It cointains a query template
```

I have tried to make a `group by` but I am having problems too.

```py
query = Zone.select(Zone,MyObject).join(Zone).group_by(MyObject.zone)
zones = list(query) # M zones, that is good but inside each zone, zone.lights has nothing and zone.myobjects is only one object no a list
zone[0].myobjects # It cointains a query template
```

I don't know how to procceed. It is important to have all the columns ready to be accessed and not as a template query because I have a lot of entries.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#avoiding-the-n-1-problem

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#list-users-and-all-their-tweets

Do you even read documentation?

Comment: Yes but problem was I had reading 2.1 one. Before you answer I found the solution using aggregate_rows and later I see that updating to 3.x it has been removed. I am using prefetch and now it is working. Thanks